# Move apk from alpha testing to production in google play

Tags: android

Hi I have uploaded my app as open alpha testing in play store.Now I want to move my app from alpha testing to production .Can anyone know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

In Developer Console, in the APK section of your app, make sure your in "Advanced Mode" not "simple mode". 
In the Alpha builds tab, next to your alpha build press "Publish Now". or "Move to Production" then "Publish Now".   If my memory serves me right.?

Comment: hii have tried it but says me this apk version code is already available try another apk

Comment: @Adarsh you have to increment your version code in the *gradle.properties* file

Comment: That error explains exactly whats happening, Your Alpha is the same as or lower that your current published version number.  If You change the version code in your manifest.xml and re build app then upload to production this should work.  eg.   if your Current Published Version is "1_0_0" and your current Alpha build is Version is "1_0_0" you will not be able to publish Alpha.   If Alpha build was Version is "1_0_1" then "move to production" should work.

Comment: how much time is it going to take the console to shift an app from closed alpha to production?